# push some json data to empty array in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

i have following data

```
myArray = [ { Tests: [ [Object] ],
    _id: '52bd60d72270a398d3f87302',
    browser: [ 'FF' ],
    id: '71',
    mode: 'weekly',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
    server: '172.16.2.120' },
  { Tests: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    _id: '52c247f1cf0060b8cce84b42',
    browser: [ 'FF' ],
    id: '45',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
    server: '172.16.2.120' },
  { _id: '52ca2b0dafcec877d925d111',
    Tests: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    browser: [ 'FF', 'IE' ],
    id: '37',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-32',
    server: '172.16.2.120' } ];
```

I only want to push some these values to a newArray as follows.  How it is possible? I am working in node.js.

```
newArray = [{    
    browser: [ 'FF' ],
    id: '71'},   
  {     
    browser: [ 'FF' ],
    id: '45'},    
  {   
    browser: [ 'FF', 'IE' ],
    id: '37'},
   ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
var newArray = myArray.map(function(obj) {
    return {browser : obj.browser, id : obj.id}
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dTPm9/)

Comment: but it is not working..showing 'TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map''

Comment: node.js has Array.map, so I guess you either don't have an array, or you're testing in something other than node.js ?